# Adding a model to an array of models in MVC

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a controller method that looks like this

```
            foreach (Site s in sites)
            {
             SummaryReportModel[] summaryReports = new SummaryReportModel[sites.Count + 1];

             foreach (OffSiteItemDetails d in s.ItemDetails)
             {

             model.OffReportColumns = new List<string>()
            {
                s.Name,
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost",
                "",
                "",
                "Average Cost (With labour)"
            };
            model.OffReportRows = new List<List<string>>()
            {

                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Parts",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiPartCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "600000 series",
                    osiOpc6[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "700000 series",
                    osiOpc7[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "800000 series",
                    osiOpc8[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Tools",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                     "",
                     "",
                    osiTools[s.ID].ToString("C2"),

                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "900000 series",
                    osiOpc9[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "Other",
                    osiOpco[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    ""
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Components",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiLoCompCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "Items",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiLoItemCost[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
            };
            model.OffReporTotal = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiTotal[s.ID].ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    osiFltotal[s.ID].ToString("C2")
                },
            };

        }

 }

            model.osiGrandTotal = new List<List<string>>()
            {
                 new List<string>()
              {
                    "OSI Grand Total",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ostotal.ToString("C2"),
                    "",
                    "",
                    ofltotal.ToString("C2")
                },
            };


            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Model

```
 public class SummaryReportModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
        public string OffReportTitle { get; set; }
        public List<string> ValuationColumns { get; set; }
        public List<string> OffReportColumns { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> ValuationRows { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> OffReportRows { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Total { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> OffReporTotal { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Tital { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> SecondTital { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> osiGrandTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my view

```
 <tr style="color:black">
                @foreach (var col in Model.OffReportColumns)
                {
                    <th>@col </th>
                }
            </tr>

            @foreach (var row in Model.OffReportRows)
            {
                <tr style="color:black">
                    @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                }
                </tr>
                }


            @foreach (var row in Model.OffReporTotal)
            {
                <tr style="font-size: 20px">
                    @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                        <td>@cell</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
```

Currently what happens is that the table will get all the data for the 'site' but when it loops the data gets overwritten so then it only returns the data for the last 'site' in the table. I am not sure of what is the best way to go about fixing this but I was thinking maybe if I was able to create an array that would store each table that then I'd be able to return that to the view and display the table data. But I am not sure if this is even possible. Or maybe there is a better way to do what I am trying to do. I am open to suggestions

Comment: I can't understand exactly what the problem is. However you create this array for each site as you can see in your code - `SummaryReportModel[] summaryReports = new SummaryReportModel[sites.Count + 1];` just a suggestion - maybe this should be initialized before the first foreach?

Comment: Right now as it loops through the array it overwrites the table that it just had created. So in result the view is only returning the table of the last site ID that was in the loop. I want my view to return every table. Not just the last one that was looped through

Comment: Instead of overwriting on each pass through the loop you need to use the List.Add method to add the values from each site. For example model.OffReportColums.Add({ // your object });